# Simplifying processing modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm running a process that requires me to change the amount of data input depending on the situation.  With my current system I need to have a separate model depending on the number of files I need to process.  I would like something that's more flexible so I only need one model that can handle different amounts of files.

What I'm trying to do is find any point outside of a buffer around the input layer(s).

Here's what my model currently looks like but it will only process 8 inputs into 'images'.   I need it to be able to handle any amount eg 1-8.  I have them set as optional but it still errors saying I need data.

[image]

Comment: Are the parameters for each tool the same? I.e. `Reproject layer1` has the same CRS settings as `Reproject layer6` or `Convert points to line(s) 4` has the same field settings as `Convert points to line(s) 8` etc?

Comment: Yes, the parameters are the same for all.  I tried to simplify it further by using a merge function to merge all the files before running them through the other processes but ran into the same issue.  All the inputs must be used.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert your model into a **script** and take advantage of the [`multiple vector`](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html) parameter which allows you specify x number of input layers.

The below code hopefully tries to emulate (to some extent) what you're trying to achive. For each input layer:

1. Runs the `qgis:reprojectlayer` on the input layer.
2. Runs the `saga:convertpointstoline` on the output of Step 1.
3. Runs the `qgis:fixeddistancebuffer`on the output of Step 2.
4. Repeat for any other input layers

When that is complete, it then:

5. Appends the paths of the outputs of Step 3 into a list.
6. Runs the `"qgis:mergevectorlayers"` on all layers in the list.
7. Finally runs the `"qgis:difference"` tool using the `Junction points` layer and the `merged` layer.

---

Here is the code which you can modify the parameters for each tool to fit your needs such as the CRS or the field names etc. Go to:

```
Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script
```

Enter the code and save it into your `/.qgis2/processing/scripts/` directory:

```
##Example=name
##Images=multiple vector
##Junction_points=vector point
##Missed_points=output vector

layers = Images.split(';')
layers_for_merging = []

for lyr in layers:
    layer = processing.getObjectFromUri(lyr)
    outputs_0 = processing.runalg("qgis:reprojectlayer", layer, 'ESPG:27700', None)
    outputs_1 = processing.runalg("saga:convertpointstolines", outputs_0['OUTPUT'], 'field_1', 'field_2', None)
    outputs_2 = processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", outputs_1['LINES'], 0.1, 99, False, None)
    layers_for_merging.append(outputs_2['OUTPUT'])

merged_layers = processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", ';'.join(layers_for_merging), None)
result = processing.runalg("qgis:difference", Junction_points, merged_layers['OUTPUT'], True, Missed_points)
```

---

This is the interface when you run the script:

[image: Example]

---

Example:

Here are some basic point layers:

[image: Example layers]

This is now running the script (for the `qgis:mergevectorlayers`, I replaced `None` with a path to show how the merged layer looks for testing):

[image: Result]

The black stars are the missed points as they lie outside the merged buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Joseph.  Unfortunately I couldn't get your code to work.  The merged layer output 3 giant ovals but the difference function didn't seem to work. This is with the parameters I need.

```
##MissedPoints=name
##Images=multiple vector
##Junction_points=vector point
##Merge=output vector
##Missed_points=output vector

layers = Images.split(';')
layers_for_merging = []

for lyr in layers:
    layer = processing.getObjectFromUri(lyr)
    outputs_0 = processing.runalg("qgis:reprojectlayer", layer, 'ESPG:102005', None)
    outputs_1 = processing.runalg("saga:convertpointstolines", outputs_0['OUTPUT'], 'gps_date', 'north', None)
    outputs_2 = processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", outputs_1['LINES'], 7.0, 5.0, False, None)
    layers_for_merging.append(outputs_2['OUTPUT'])

merged_layers = processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", ';'.join(layers_for_merging), Merge)
result = processing.runalg("qgis:difference", Junction_points, merged_layers['OUTPUT'], True, Missed_points)
```

Here's one I tried by outputting the model to python then editing.  It works for a couple files but if I input more than 3 it kills Qgis.

```
##missed junction points merge 3=name
##images=multiple vector
##junctionpoints=vector
##missedpoints=output vector

outputs_QGISMERGEVECTORLAYERS_1=processing.runalg('qgis:mergevectorlayers', [images],None)
outputs_QGISREPROJECTLAYER_1=processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', outputs_QGISMERGEVECTORLAYERS_1['OUTPUT'],'EPSG:102005',None)
outputs_SAGACONVERTPOINTSTOLINES_1=processing.runalg('saga:convertpointstolines', outputs_QGISREPROJECTLAYER_1['OUTPUT'],'gps_date','north',None)
outputs_QGISFIXEDDISTANCEBUFFER_1=processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', outputs_SAGACONVERTPOINTSTOLINES_1['LINES'],7.0,5.0,False,None)
outputs_QGISDIFFERENCE_1=processing.runalg('qgis:difference', junctionpoints,outputs_QGISFIXEDDISTANCEBUFFER_1['OUTPUT'],False,missedpoints)
```